# Greater/Less than operator behave differently than equal operator on Q promises

Tags: javascript, promise, comparison, q

When using Javascript promises, I ran into this weird behavior. Consider the following code:

```
var Q = require('q');

var d1 = Q.defer();
var d2 = Q.defer();

compare(d1.promise, d2.promise);

d1.resolve(3);
d2.resolve(3);

function compare(a, b) {
 Q.all([a,b]).then(function(results) {
  console.log('a: ' + a + '   b: ' + b);
  var result =  (a == b)? 1: -1;
  console.log(result);

 });
}
```

When you run this code, you get -1. I realize that I am not evaluating the results variable being passed in to the anonymous function by then (as I should). My specific question is this:

If you change the loose equality (==) operator with a greater than (>) or less than (<) operator, and change the values being passed to resolve(), then the code works as one would expect.

So the strange behavior is that == behaves differently in regards to promises than < or >. It seems as if less than (<) and greater than (>) somehow have a special ability to await the result of promises, while the equality operator (==, ===) does not.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: no, `<`/`>` don't await the results of promises. *You* did, by using `Q.all` and a `then` callback. Only by then, `.valueOf` does give the respective result - see @FelixKling's answer for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of equality the result is `false` because you are comparing two objects that are not identical:

From the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-abstract-equality-comparison):

> **7.2.12 Abstract Equality Comparison**
>
> ...
>   3. If Type(x) is the same as Type(y), then
>       Return the result of performing Strict Equality Comparison x === y.
>   ...

and

> **7.2.13 Strict Equality Comparison**
>
> ...
>   8. If x and y are the same Object value, return true.
>   9. Return false.

---

However, [the relational comparison](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-abstract-relational-comparison) is only defined for strings and numbers. Hence JavaScript performs **type conversion** before comparing the promises. In this process it will call the objects' [**`valueOf`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) methods, so it will actually compare the return values of `a.valueOf` and `b.valueOf`. In addition to that, [Q overrides the default `valueOf` implementation to return the resolved value](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/v1/q.js#L561-L571):

```
// XXX deprecated
promise.valueOf = function () {
    if (messages) {
        return promise;
    }
    var nearerValue = nearer(resolvedPromise);
    if (isPromise(nearerValue)) {
        resolvedPromise = nearerValue; // shorten chain
    }
    return nearerValue;
};
```

But you can see that the library discourages it, most likely because [standard promises](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-promise-objects) don't implement such a behavior.

---

Simplified demonstration:

```
> var a = {valueOf: function() { return 0; }};
> var b = {valueOf: function() { return 0; }};
> a == b
false
> a >= b
true
```